# vue3/vuetify - Missing required param when going to a route that doesn't required any param

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-router

Using last version of Vue3, Vue-router and Vuetify.

When I'm on the '/a/:accountId/people/:personId/emails' route, and when I wanna go back on the '/a/:accountId/people/' route, I have an error "Missing required param "personId".

Looks like the route is changing too fast and the actual route asking for the required param "PersonId" that isn't required on the destination route.

**Here my router:**

```
export default {
  path: '/a/:accountId/',
  props: true,
  component: AccountLayout,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'people',
      name: 'app-account-people',
      component: PeopleList,
    },
    {
      path: 'people/:personId',
      props: true,
      component: PeopleDetailLayout,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'emails',
          props: true,
          name: 'app-account-person-emails',
          component: PeopleDetailEmails,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

sample of the Layout component:

```
<div>
  <v-card>
   <v-tabs color="primary">
     <v-tab
       variant="text"
       icon="mdi-chart-box-outline"
       :to="{
         name: 'app-account-person-emails',
       }"
        exact
        link
     >
        ABUTTON
     </v-tab>
   </v-tabs>
     </v-card>
     <v-divider />
       <div class="pa-4 pt-1">
        {{ person }}
        <router-view />
       </div>
</div>
```

If I do something like this it works:

```
:to="{
  name: 'app-account-person-emails',
  params: { personId: props.personId },
}"
```

But I don't get why I do have to pass this as there is "props: true" in the "app-account-person-emails" route. And I have the same App with a vue2 version and doesn't need to pass again that personId in the ":to"

- again, I want to go to the original page where personId isn't even needed.

Just in case, a part of the AccountLayout when the "app-account-people" is:

```
<v-list-item
  :to="{
    name: 'app-account-people',
  }"
prepend-icon="mdi-account-multiple"
  :title="$t('person.user', 2)"
  exact
>
</v-list-item>
```

Tried also to just creact a function and make a router.push manually (without the :to) and it also works:

```
<v-tab
   variant="text"
   icon="mdi-chart-box-outline"
   @click="test"
   exact
   link
>
  ABUTTON
</v-tab>
function test() {
  router.push({ name: 'app-account-person-emails' })
}
```

Comment: Your examples are not clear since you show links to the `app-account-person-emails` page, which does require the `personId` parameter. Have you tried to set `to="/a/123/people"` instead of using the route's name?

Comment: I don't really want to do that cause I have to repass the accountId param. 
Something is really weird cause the children "Emails.vue" has access to the "personId" props anyway (thanks to the props: true).

So you right, the page "app-account-person-emails" doesn't even require "personId"; but if I remove this link (or put a fake personId param) it will not blame me when I wanna go to another page

Comment: Have you tried to add inside the route person id a name, ```name: 'app-account-people-id'```.
And to be clear, you have the error about personId when you click on the link to ```app-account-people```?

Comment: just tried what you suggest, added a name to person id route. But same problem.
Actually I just removed the ":to" and added a "@click" with a function with router.push. It work but I don't understand why it doesn't with ":to". And yes, I have an arror about a missing "personId" param when I click on the link to app-account-people

Comment: @Jer did you find the solution yet? Struggling with the same issue. Vuetify 3, Vue 3, same problem. Can't navigate between routes even though they don't have such param